# How can you add custom R shiny input buttons? (minimal example)

Tags: r, shiny

I'm programming my second R Shiny app, and my knowledge is growing.
But my skills on HTML, CSS and JS are still poor.
I am wondering how to add custom buttons in R shiny app.

**Can we do this easily with a package or something to creat a new button?

Can you help me and show me how to implement one button please.

I have tried many things and I am lost.**
For purpose of training, I'm trying to implement a small tool found on the internet (details below)

<strike>Let says I want to add 2 buttons:
Button1
Button2</strike>

I want to add it into R shiny: default view is the grey square, but highlighting in yellow when hover it

**If multiple click on the said button occurs, the value will grow like this:

One click on Button0-> c("0")

Two click on Button0-> c("0","0")**

(eventually, I would like to know how to add "CLEAR" button to empty the string vector)

The idea and source materials come from:
Original website: www(dot)ookii(dot)org/Software/Dni
Corresponding JS: www(dot)ookii(dot)org/Scripts/dni.js

---

EDIT 1 :

## Minimal Exemple

Here is minimal example code I'm struggling with

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for miles per gallon app ----
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  # App title ----
  headerPanel("Miles Per Gallon"),

  # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
  sidebarPanel(),

  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  mainPanel(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("div.dniButton
                      {
                       overflow: hidden;
                       height: 27px;
                       width: 34px;
                       float: left;
                       margin: 3px;
                       }
                       div.dniButton:hover input
                       {
                       margin-top: -27px;
                       }"))
      ),
    tags$button(
      id = "dni0",
      class = "dniButton",
      img(src = "http://www.ookii.org/Content/software/images/dni/button0.png"))
  )
)

# Define server logic to plot various variables against mpg ----
server <- function(input, output) {

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## CURRENT view of the button

[image: Actual view of the button from the code above]

## WANTED  BEHAVIOR

I dont know how to make the button like this:
[image: Button 0]

Then when hover it, it should become yellow:
[image: Button 0 highlight]

When you hover it, it should also displays a tooltip indicating 0

When this button is clicked, it send "0" (character) to R shiny server

Comment: You should reformat your question with Code separately. Also please specify your question clearly. Please add your supportive picture for better understanding.

Comment: Is it better now?